# Plot multiple histograms with seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, histogram, seaborn

I have a data frame with 36 columns. I want to plot histograms for each feature in one go (6x6) using seaborn. Basically reproducing `df.hist()` but with seaborn. My code below shows the plot for only the first feature and all other come empty.

[image]

Test dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 36)), columns=range(0,36))
```

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns
# plot
f, axes = plt.subplots(6, 6, figsize=(20, 20), sharex=True)
for feature in df.columns:
    sns.distplot(df[feature] , color="skyblue", ax=axes[0, 0])
```

Comment: `ax=axes[0, 0]` means that you plot always to the first axes. This is what you observe as well. Maybe you want to plot to different axes?

Comment: Oh, that's true. How should I change it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess it would make sense to loop over the axes and features simultaneously.

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(6, 6, figsize=(20, 20), sharex=True)
for ax, feature in zip(axes.flat, df.columns):
    sns.distplot(df[feature] , color="skyblue", ax=ax)
```

Numpy arrays are flattened by row-wise, i.e. you would get the first 6 features in the first row, the features 6 to 11 in the second row etc.

If this is not what you want, you can define the index for the axes array manually,

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(6, 6, figsize=(20, 20), sharex=True)
    for i, feature in enumerate(df.columns):
        sns.distplot(df[feature] , color="skyblue", ax=axes[i%6, i//6])
```

e.g. the above will fill the subplots column by column.